# Do the frequencies inherent in tinnitus have any side effects?

Tags: hearing, ear, frequency, tinnitus

I've heard that certain frequencies naturally have some autonomic effects in some people. I've also heard that tinnitus sometimes falls into that range.

I can't really find much information on these ideas together as everything that comes up about tinnitus related anxiety is about how it causes stress when people worry about the condition's effect on their lives, or about anxiety being able to exacerbate tinnitus.

[Low frequency noise and annoyance](http://www.noiseandhealth.org/article.asp?issn=1463-1741;year=2004;volume=6;issue=23;spage=59;epage=72;aulast=Leventhall)

[Stress Recovery Effects of High- and Low-Frequency Amplified Music on Heart Rate Variability](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5021883/)

[The Sound of Stress](https://www.pituitaryworldnews.org/the-sound-of-stress/)

[Tinnitus frequencies](https://www.audionotch.com/blog/2015/06/24/what-are-the-most-common-tinnitus-frequencies/)

Comment: Specifically, can you link us to where you read this? Just saying you heard something doesn't make it true.

Comment: @CareyGregory Done, though I dunno if I did it right or provided enough. I honestly thought that sound having effects on us was already pretty widely agreed upon. I hadn't really read about any of this in any one specific place.

Comment: You did fine and added more than enough. Thank you.